# Stage styling in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, popupwindow, scene, stage

How to apply StageStyle.utility and StageStyle.undecorated to the same stage.

I am using this for the internal window/ popup.

Or if I have to follow any other solution please do stuggest.

Thanks

Comment: There is no question. Please add your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wanted to create a internal window/ popup window. How to create it?  The window should be undecorated and aslo untitled #fireandfuel

Comment: There is no such thing as `StageStyle.UNTITLED` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html)). An `UNDECORATED` stage has no title anyway.

Comment: @James_D sorry it is StageStyle.UTILITY

Comment: I guess you need to hide the title of window according to your conditions `UNDECORATED` and `UTILITY` for the same stage, you have a solution to make your stage `UNDECORATED` and add a button on `TOP_RIGHT`.

Comment: @menai ala eddine the problem with the undecorated is , it is creating the new window icon in taskbar. But I want to use it as the dialog box

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem :**

Application two styles `StageStyle.UTILITY`and `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` for the same stage.

**Because**

> you asked for suggestion 
>    to solve your problem.

**Suggestion :**

I suggest to use [in-sideFX/Undecorator](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator) 
 [(Downlaod the jar file and add it into your project)](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator/tree/master/dist) then we will make some modifications to keep your need ,I tried to create this sample of code for creating a Popup window inside parent window (Owner window) :
package javafxpopup;

```
import insidefx.undecorator.Undecorator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 *
 * @author Menai Ala Eddine
 */
public class Undecorated extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Stage popStage = new Stage();
                popStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                StackPane root = new StackPane();
                root.getChildren().add(new Label("I'm popup window"));
                applyModification(popStage, root);
                popStage.show();

            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,500,500));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void applyModification(Stage primaryStage, StackPane root) {
        Undecorator undecorator = new Undecorator(primaryStage, root);
        undecorator.getStylesheets().add("/skin/undecorator.css");
        Scene scene = new Scene(undecorator, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.setFill(null);
        Node stageMenu = undecorator.lookup("#StageMenu");
        stageMenu.setVisible(false);
        Node maximize = undecorator.lookup(".decoration-button-maximize");
        maximize.setVisible(false);
        Node manimize = undecorator.lookup(".decoration-button-minimize");
        manimize.setVisible(false);
        Node restore = undecorator.lookup(".decoration-button-fullscreen");
        restore.setVisible(false);

    }

}
```

By clicking the button the pop window will showing into owner window :

[image]

As you see `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` and `StageStyle.UTILITY` in the same time.

**PS:** it is a suggestion you can find many solutions.